# Keep div open on page navigation

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i downloaded a facebook-like chat application, i edited it to fit for my website but i'm having problem with keeping the chat session open while navigating other pages.. thanks to all that try to help initially, some suggested AJAX request.. i tried it out with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
  var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
             document.getElementById("site-body-content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
       }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

}

each time i create a link, i'll have to re-write this function changing the name and the page in 
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "pagename", true);
 what i want to do now is to save the stress of re-writing a function for each page created.

Comment: Do you really think your question has enough information in it to be answerable? Show what you've tried already, and add more description of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a 'div window'.

Facebook does it by updating the url in the bar, but requesting the new page information through an AJAX request, effectively avoiding what would be considered normal navigation.

Comment: thanks.. the ajax request really workout fine.. but i'm having a little problem wit it.. i've restructured the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have basic knowledge of what JavaScript is, and the difference between it and php, especially since your creating something like a chat.. I would have to remind you that JavaScript is a client side scripting language. So it renders after the page is loaded, manipulating DOM elements and whatever have you have the page is done rending. So with that you will need to create some logic that lives off of Cookies maybe? or PHP based sessions set with AJAX to a per container ID to reopen upon page load or stay minimize upon page load, load the associated data per element on page load and so on.

However helping you is going to be next to impossible as there is literally hundreds of ways you can handle this type of thing. So short of you providing code for all of us here on Stack to look at to help you assess your issues better we can't offer much help.

A chat script to begin with is hard enough to sort out and my experience here on stack is most people aren't keen on helping if the question sounds like do it for me rather than look at what I have, how can I fix this, or improve this, or do this better.

Comment: thanks...... i downloaded the chat, include some links. what i notice was when i initiate a chat session and i click a link, the chat is refreshed. that was when the idea of keeping the chat open.. don't have much about javascript but i know it will be used to solve my problem... i need ideas on how to go about it

Comment: If you downloaded a canned script, more so if you paid for it, it should work out of the box the way you expect or hope. But then again some of those canned ones aren't the best. Again all in all, it comes down to what your code is doing, with out any of that code, or errors being given to you from it, no one is going to be able to help you. We don't know the structure of your code or anything else, and as I said before theres hundreds of ways of doing just about anything, there is no specific way or standard way. We would need to know a lot more to help

Comment: i've restructured the question with a little improvement